# How to randomize, retrieve and prevent a duplicates from being drawn in a table?

Tags: php, mysql

Good day, Everyone!

I'm currently have a working code block that randomizes a MYSQL tab

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dbPosDuplicate");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)){
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $random = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tbData order by RAND() LIMIT 1");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($random);
    echo $row['firstname'];
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I would like to modify it in a way that it would prevent duplicates from being drawn - I'm assuming that it would have a button 'reset' the session and so on and so forth.

Is there a way to minimally adjust the code and it make it work like its supposed to?

**Edit:

I also have an HTML file where I present the results of the PHP code block above, something that looks like this:

```
                    <td bgcolor=#DAA520>
                            <center>    
                                    <a href="#" onclick="randomer();">
                                        <SPAN STYLE="FONT-FAMILY: TRAJAN PRO; FONT-SIZE:70%;">  
                                            RANDOMIZER!
                                        </SPAN>
                                    </a>
                            </center>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </TABLE>
            <table align=center border=0 width=1050PX>
                <TR>
                    <TD>
                            <CENTER>
                                <SPAN STYLE="color:#F0E6C3; FONT-FAMILY: TRAJAN PRO; FONT-SIZE:350%;">  
                                    <div onclick="randomer();" style="height:260px;overflow:auto; width: 86%; float:right; left:-8%; bottom:-8%; position:relative;" id="KaloysRevenge"></div>
                                    <a href="#" onclick="randomer();"></a>
                                </SPAN>
                            </CENTER>
                    </TD>
```

Comment: `it would prevent duplicates from being drawn`-> each time when this code will run, previous value will automatically removed. So what do you meand by duplicate. Are you showing previous values also somewhere?

Comment: Yes, I have an HTML file that displays the results of the PHP block on top - it just runs the PHP code and displays the names that the PHP code block randomized.

Comment: so it's like a butoon to run script again and again and the output shown in html along with previous output. Please share your html along with full php code so that people can easily understand your problem and answer you.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably have to add a field to your table showing whether the specific record had already been asked.

That means that after retrieving the row you would have to update the record with the retrieved id.

I can think of three types of fields:

1. A simple boolean flag. In your query you would add a "WHERE NOT hasBeenShown"
2. A date or timestamp. It's hard to say how exactly you want it to work, but could be used in an ORDER BY instead of WHERE clause
3. **A fixed Random field**: At the very beginning, execute a query, assigning a random number to that field. Then, in your SELECT query use

   ```
   ORDER BY randomField LIMIT 1 OFFSET x
   ```

   where x is the number of previous elements displayed.

If all you want is to show the entire table at a time, but randomized, just get rid of the LIMIT 1:

```
SELECT * FROM tbData order by RAND()
```

More details that might allow us to help you better:

- Do you want the randomization / prevent duplicates to work for just one or several users?
- Are the items shown going to reset at some point, i.e., when the entire table has been shown, should it restart?

Comment: First of all, thank you for your response, highly appreciated!

-Do you want the randomization / prevent duplicates to work for just one or several users?: PREVENT FOR ALL USERS, THE NAMES SHOULD ONLY DISPLAY ONCE PER 'SESSION'.
-Are the items shown going to reset at some point, i.e., when the entire table has been shown, should it restart? - I'M THINKING OF A RESET BUTTON, MAYBE?

Comment: That's pretty hard to do, then. You either need a separate table storing the (random) order per user - or you just have the above-suggested stored (random) order (#3), but then it's the same order for all users (not sure if that's ok with you?)